# Cache linked pages in accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, caching

If a valid, upvoted question with a thorough, upvoted or especially, accepted, answer contains links, it'd be great if SO cached an imageless/stripped (if not full!) version of just the linked-to page.

It's painful to find the answer to the question you're asking then you click on someone's suggested "Great article - must read:" and the page is removed/gone/site-down.

Perhaps there could be a "flag missing link" button which will insert a prompt to view SO's cache of the page **or** try the original link.

This is, of course, far more prevalent with older questions, but let's face it, SO isn't young anymore in the grand scheme of things and this would be, in my opinion, a welcome growth for our wonderful, growing community.

Comment: This doesn't concern deleted posts. It concerns links to "must reads" that have since disappeared. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364498/drupal-on-git-what-to-do-with-the-database 2nd answer for an example. The opc.com.au. link is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

[Link only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer) answers are considered low quality answers and are often placed into the Review Queue, where users with enough rep will see them and provide feedback to the answerer. The current auto-inserted comment is:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

This is to help encourage people to bring the required bits of another page into the answer on stack overflow to avoid the issue you are seeing.

If you do have a broken link and can find it's new home on Google or on the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org), then feel free to suggest an edit.